# Java method signatur ignore unequal class return

Tags: java, function, types, return, extends

Ok I try to execute this:

```
public class A
{
}
public class B extends A
{
}
public class UseAandB {
  public static B from() {return new B();}
  public static A from() {return new A();}
}
```

But I can not execute this because B extends A. Why do this not work ? And how can I fix this ?

**EDIT:** My first guess seems to be wrong the return signature of a method is not a part of the official method signature, again java fails on every level of logic. Thx to [Andy Turner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3788176/andy-turner)

Comment: The program has absolutely no way to tell if you want to call the first or second from() method because they are identical in every way besides the return value.

Comment: Use en IDE to code, it'll give you that kind of error, and lot of other ones ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But I can not execute this because B extends A

No, you can't *compile* this because you have [two override-equivalent methods in the same class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.2). It wouldn't work if you changed one of the methods to return, say, `String` either.

Return type isn't part of the method signature in Java, so you can't define two methods which only differ in the return type.

The easiest fix is to rename at least one of the methods, e.g. `fromB` and `fromA`. Alternatively, put the methods in separate classes.

(There are other ways to get it to compile, but these basically involve adding unnecessary additional things to the method signature, like extra unused parameters. Renaming the methods is the cleanest approach.)